# Common image to debug Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am looking for a common **container image** which I can use to debug things in Kubernetes.

`busybox` does not work, since it has a bug with `nslookup`.

`alpine` does not contain `curl`.

`ubuntu` does not contain `curl`.

I would like to have some common tools like: nslookup, netstat, dig, curl, traceroute, tcptraceroute, ...

I know that I could `apt update; apt install ...` but I would like to have an image which is ready to use.

Comment: nc is a good tool that can be used.itrs not going to cover all your needs be at the same its called swiss army knife.

Comment: @ZarehKasparian I guess we are talking about different things here. The tool `nc` is a command line tool. I am searching for a **container image**

Comment: you are exactly talking about command line tools --> "I would like to have some common tools like: nslookup, netstat, dig, curl, traceroute, tcptraceroute, ". thus I have introuduced you with nc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netshoot:

https://github.com/nicolaka/netshoot

> Purpose: Docker and Kubernetes network troubleshooting can become
> complex. With proper understanding of how Docker and Kubernetes
> networking works and the right set of tools, you can troubleshoot and
> resolve these networking issues. The netshoot container has a set of
> powerful networking tshooting tools that can be used to troubleshoot
> Docker networking issues. Along with these tools come a set of
> use-cases that show how this container can be used in real-world
> scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

The recent [`koolkit` project](https://github.com/lightrun-platform/koolkits#readme) seems in the spirit of what you are asking for

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, the easiest solution will be to create your custom image. It will be difficult to find an image that will meet your expectations in 100%. A much better solution is to create one image for you that you will use later in the future. As a base image, you can use eg. [Alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/).

> It is a minimal Docker image based on Alpine Linux with a complete package index and only 5 MB in size!

For this you will add the necessary tools and it's ready - you will have a docker image, which you will later use in testing and debugging Kubernetes.

See also tutorials about Kubernetes debugging:

- [Trobleshoot Applications](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application/)
- [Monitoring, Logging, and Debugging](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/)
- [Debug Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/)